# celery: ImportError: No module named time

Tags: django, celery

Trying to start `celery`. I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/finbee/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/finbee/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/finbee/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/finbee/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/finbee/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/finbee/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_beat/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .clockedschedule import clocked
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/finbee/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_beat/clockedschedule.py", line 6, in <module>
    from celery.utils.time import maybe_make_aware
ImportError: No module named time
```

I'm use

```
celery == 3.1.25
django-celery == 3.1.17
django-celery-beat == 1.5.0
```

*Celery versions> 4.0 cannot be used.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the changelog](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/blob/master/Changelog#L100), `django-celery-beat` 1.0.1+ requires Celery 4.0.

You could try django-celery-beat 1.0.0, but if that doesn't work, then you might not be able to use `django-celery-beat` until you can upgrade to Celery 4.0.

Comment: latest version django-celery of requires celery<4.0,>=3.1.15 while django-celery-beat reqires celery>=4? lol

Comment: @JayVasant since celery 3.1, you don't need to install django-celery to [use celery with Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django).